# Flutter Container height/width

Tags: flutter, image, containers

[image: BoxFit.cover]
[image: BoxFit.fill]

Hey guys, so my problem is that the image should take all the space in the box (I got that) but the image looks weird.
Could you help me?

```
child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20, 10, 20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 2,
                        color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                      ),
                    ),
                    height: 350,
                    width: 350,
                    child: Container(
                        height: 350,
                        width: 350,
                        child: FittedBox(child: infoBank[PicNumber].image,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Can you paste your code as text (you can use ``` to create a code block)? That would help trying to recreate it

Comment: Yes, wait one second (I got it now but the picture looks a bit weird)

Comment: Here you go I posted the changes

Comment: Use the widget FittedBox to fill the image in it, see the docs for more info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `BoxFit.cover` in your `Image`:

```dart
fit: BoxFit.cover
```

Alternatively, use `BoxFit.fillHeight` or `BoxFit.fillWidth` where appropriate for only one direction.

```dart
child: Image.network(
 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/Peanuts_maize_chips_2.jpg/1920px-Peanuts_maize_chips_2.jpg',
 fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
```

Comment: I tried it but it takes than more space then I want (I added a picture to my question)

Comment: I see that in your code you're using two nested containers, then a fitted box and then finally the image. If you just have 1 container and then the image, does it still not work?

Comment: Yes, now I deleted the last on and used BoxFit.fill but the image is still distorted
By the way thank you for your help

Comment: It is expected that `BoxFit.fill` distorts the image if the container aspect ratio is different from the image. Take a look at this page: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit.html it mentions you can use some `clipBehavior` to make it work the way you want, I think!